# Compare two fields in a MongoDB aggregation's match on a looked up value

Tags: mongodb

I want to compare two dynamic fields like I'd do with:

```java
$where: [ "$foo_update > $bar_update" ]
```

I need this to get a bunch of objects that must be updated. It depends on several conditions if they must get updated, so that's why I want to make it with an aggregation.

The current query for the related part looks like:

```java
[
  { $sort: { "updated_at": 1 } 
  { $group: {
    "_id"          : "$bar",
    "foo"          : { "$first" : "$foo" },
    "bar"          : { "$first" : "$bar" },
    "last_update"  : { "$last " : "$updated_at" } 
  } },
  { $lookup: {
    "from"         : "table_foo",
    "localField"   : "foo",
    "foreignField" : "_id",
    "as"           : "foo"
  } },
  { $lookup: {
    "from"         : "table_bar",
    "localField"   : "bar",
    "foreignField" : "_id",
    "as"           : "bar"
  } }
]
```

Here I could follow with another `$group` operator to get the values I need out to the top-level. But I cannot do that with the lookup values as it is mostly an array of items.

Here, one item is expected (and I make a query for that too as we need update if the other item is removed).

So now I want to compare the `$last_update` and the `foo.update_at` field. It would look something like this in my head.

```java
$match: {
  "foo": {
    $elemMatch: {
      "updated_at": { "$gte": "$last_update" }
    }
  }
}
```

- Is this even possible?
- If yes, how would you do it?

Comment: before $match you should use $unwind, it will convert your array to object https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

Comment: @styopdev Not necessarily. There are other ways to deal with arrays than `$unwind`. But it is indeed unclear as to what the "joined" data is going to look like. One to One, One to Many? Also not really clear what the intent here is at the end. If the comparison is not true then remove the "document", or just remove the unmatched array entry ( or entries as appropriate ). That could do with some clarification.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I want to get a list of records that must get updated (or removed in some cases). After this query we pass the selected records to the backend, so it can work with it and decide what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And yes, it is possible. It turned out that you can move the value of the array to the top with operators like `$max`.

So my solution looks like this now:

```java
[
  /** the beginning of the query above **/
  { $group: {
    "_id"         : "$_id",
    "foo"         : { "$first" : "$foo" },
    "foo_updated" : { "$max"   : "$foo_updated_at" },
    "bar"         : { "$first" : "$bar" },
    "bar_updated" : { "$max"   : "$bar.updated_at" },
    "last_update" : { "$last " : "$updated_at" } 
  }, $project: {
    "_id"         : "$_id",
    "foo"         : "$foo",
    "foo_updated" : { "$gt": [ "$foo_updated", "$last_create" ] },
    "bar"         : "$bar",
    "bar_updated" : { "$gt": [ "$bar_updated", "$last_create" ] },
    "last_create" : "$last_create"
  }, $match: {
    "$or": [
      /** other conditions **/
      { "foo_updated": true },
      { "bar_updated": true }
    ]
  } }
]
```